# simple_form grouped_select group_method with filtered data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

Is it possible to filter data of the group_method in a grouped select in simple form??

```
<%= f.association :user,
                  collection:companies,
                  as: :grouped_select,
                  group_method: :users%>
```

I just want to be able to insert some of the users not all of them those who are linked to a project another model that i have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to filter using `simple_form`'s group_method. Even if it was possible, I would be inefficient. What you need instead is to filter companies, which have only those users who is involved in the project.

Comment: thank you but it wouldn't work because any company can have those user

Comment: it's actually companies and in every company we have multiple users some of them are assigned to a project and some of them are not so i have to be able to have only users assigned to project